# Onchange action dropdownlist

Tags: javascript, onchange, html-select

When I change the dropdown value, nothing happens?

Is there something wrong with this?

```
<option value='8' onchange="window.open('availability.jsp?user=99&clickeddate=2013-04-12&month=8','_self')">September</option><
```

Onchange is the correct action?

Regards

Answer (score 2):

The `onChange` event is associated with the `<select>` tag and not with the `<option>` tag.

Try

```
<select onChange="window.open('availability.jsp?user=99&clickeddate=2013-04-12&month=8','_self')">
<option>option 1</option>
<option>option 2</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because the `onchange` event needs to be in the parent `select` element.